# Chrome Extension : Cant appendchild in my popup file

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I want to make myself a password manager, just for private use. I know it's unsafe but I don't care.

I am having a problem with making my list of passwords in the ui/default_popup file. I have made a div, with a scrollbar, and I want some javascript to add some divs inside this div, with my passwords, but I can't seem to add items.

Right now I've tried setting it up, so there is a button, and when I press it, it adds a div inside my div. This works fine if I open it in a browser, but it won't work if I use it as my extension, simply nothing happens when I click the button.

Manifest.json:

```
{
  "name": "Password Manager",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "version": "2",
  "version_name": "alpha 1",
  "description": "Alpha for my password manager project",
  "permissions": [
    "activeTab",
    "tabs",
    "http://*/*", "https://*/*"
  ],
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "default_popup": "main.html"
  }
}
```

Default_popup:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script>
      function test() {

        var element = document.createElement("div");
        element.appendChild(document.createTextNode('The man who mistook his wife for a hat'));
        document.getElementById('pswcontainer').appendChild(element);

      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="bluebox"><h1 style="color : white;">Password Manager</h1></div>
    <div id="maindiv">

      <div id="passInBox">
        <h3 style="margin-top : 0px; width : 100%; text-align : center;">Please input your universal password:</h3>
        <input style="width : 100%;" type="password" id="pswIn">
      </div>
      <div id="pswcontainer">
        <div class="psw">
          <button onclick="test()"
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
    <div class="bluebox" style="position: absolute; bottom : 10px; width : 485px;"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

css:

```
html {
  width : 500px;
  height : 590px;
  padding-left: 5px;
  padding-right: 5px;
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.bluebox {
  width : 100%;
  height : 50px;
  background-color: #3b9ddd;
  border-radius: 7px;
  padding-bottom: 1px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-top: 3px;
  margin-bottom: 3px;
}

.psw {
  height : 60px;
  width : 440px;
  margin : 5px;
  border : 1px solid black;
}

#passInBox {
  margin: auto;
  width: 60%;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  padding: 10px;

}

#maindiv {
  padding : 3px;
  height : 100%;
}

#pswcontainer {
  margin-left: 3px;
  margin-right: 3px;
  margin-bottom: 3px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  width: 467px;
  height: 373px;
  overflow-y : scroll;
  border : 2px solid black;
}
```

Comment: Running inline JS is prohibited in extensions. Move your JS code to an external file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code is fine, however it isn't working since [Chrome disallows inline scripts](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy#JSExecution) in popup (and background) pages by default.

If you inspect the popup page with devtools, you will see the following error:

> Refused to execute inline script because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' blob: filesystem: chrome-extension-resource:". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-CQOsMNzuQN6qPlC5mygdPgROsx1yvlMvr5K/pf7W2Qk='), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution.

Note that Chrome also disallows inline event handlers, like

```
<button onclick="test()">
```

> Refused to execute inline event handler because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' blob: filesystem: chrome-extension-resource:". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-...'), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution.

These errors can be avoided by creating a popup.js script with your code:

```
function test() {
  var element = document.createElement("div");
  element.appendChild(document.createTextNode('The man who mistook his wife for a hat'));
  document.getElementById('pswcontainer').appendChild(element);
}

document.querySelector('#pswcontainer button').addEventListener('click', test);
```

And then by including such script in the popup page, also note that the inline handler was removed:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="bluebox"><h1 style="color : white;">Password Manager</h1></div>
    <div id="maindiv">

      <div id="passInBox">
        <h3 style="margin-top : 0px; width : 100%; text-align : center;">Please input your universal password:</h3>
        <input style="width : 100%;" type="password" id="pswIn">
      </div>
      <div id="pswcontainer">
        <div class="psw">
          <button></button>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
    <div class="bluebox" style="position: absolute; bottom : 10px; width : 485px;"></div>

    <script src="popup.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you! This was it... If only the 'tutorial' i followed would've told me that... This is pretty imortant info